# jqGrid paginator not visible in scroll pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, pagination, jqgrid-asp.net

Version of jqGrid: Guriddo jqGrid JS 4.7.0 (2014-12-08)
Main jqGrid options:

```
mtype: 'get',
datatype: 'json',
page: 1,
scroll: 1,
rowNum: 50,
rowList: [10, 20, 50],
width: 780,
height: 250,
hidegrid: false,
multiSort: false,
autowidth: true,
multiselect: true,
ignoreCase: true,
shrinkToFit: true,
rownumbers: true,
rownumWidth: 25,
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
pager: '#jqGridPager',
viewsortcols: [false, 'horizontal', true]
```

When i set scroll to 0 - everythink is working, anybody know an easy way to enable paging and virtual scrolling together on latest versions of jqGrid?

Comment: Could you try to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and `grid.locale-en.js` which you can download from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid)? Is the problem exist in the version too or I've fixed it already?

Comment: I have tried, the same result

Comment: You should provide the demo which use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of [free jqGrid 4.8](jquery.jqGrid.src.js) (you can get it directly from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) or with jqGrid 4.7. You can use jsfiddle for example. [The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ntfw57zm/8/) shows how one can use Echo service of jqFiddle together with jqGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, not possible by design: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/689